# PySpark: Create a column with randomly selected primary keys from another dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes, A and B.

A has a primary key, key_a.

I want to create a column of foreign keys on B that selects a random key from a.

So B will look like

```
key_b | key_a
1     | 1234123
2     | 5424352
```

etc...

The keys can repeat, but the goal is for every row of B to be assigned a random value from A's key_a column.

Comment: Is `A` small enough to broadcast?

Comment: @pault I'm not familiar with broadcasting but A is roughly 10,000 rows.

Comment: How about selecting sample by fraction and setting key_b? Like `df_A.sample(0.5).withColumn("key_b", monotonically_increasing_id())`